# Qt: how to pass arguments to a Qt GUI test?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, cmake

Qt: how to pass arguments to a Qt GUI test?
Basically, how to pass arguments to `QTEST_MAIN` as you could have done with regular `main`?

To run a test for testing a Qt GUI, one can do the following:

```
>> cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(foo)
enable_testing()
# Tell CMake to run moc when necessary:
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# As moc files are generated in the binary dir, tell CMake to always look for includes there:
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5Test REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
add_test(foo foo)
target_link_libraries(foo Qt5::Test)

>> cat foo.cpp 
#include <QTest>
class Foo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void t1() { QVERIFY(true); }
};
QTEST_MAIN(Foo)
#include "foo.moc"

>> mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make all test
[ 25%] Automatic MOC for target foo
[ 25%] Built target foo_autogen
[100%] Built target foo
Running tests...
Test project /tmp/test/build
    Start 1: foo
1/1 Test #1: foo ..............................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec
```

Ok, so far, so good.

Now say I have to pass arguments to `QTEST_MAIN` in order to configure `Foo` and what's tested in `t1`: how to do this?

Basically, without Qt, one could have done:

```
set(TEST_MSG "hello" CACHE STRING "Message to print from Foo.")
add_test(NAME test COMMAND my_exe "${TEST_MSG}")
```

And then in the main of the test:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::string msg = argv[1];
  Foo f(msg);
```

Ideally, I'd like to run cmake like so `cmake -D TEST_MSG=world ..` and later on be able to retrieve the content of `TEST_MSG` (as a `std::string`) in `Foo` (to configure it): is it possible? If yes, how?

My understanding it that this reduces to "pass arguments to QTEST_MAIN": is this possible? And if yes, how to retrieve these arguments in the code (`Foo`)?

**SOLUTION**

Following @jdfa, this works:

```
>> git diff
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 5c3c430..457ad7e 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -7,5 +7,7 @@ set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
 set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
 find_package(Qt5Test REQUIRED)
 add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
-add_test(foo foo)
 target_link_libraries(foo Qt5::Test)
+set(TEST_MSG "hello" CACHE STRING "Message to print from Foo.")
+add_test(NAME foo_tst COMMAND foo)
+set_property(TEST foo_tst PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "TEST_MSG=set:${TEST_MSG}")
diff --git a/foo.cpp b/foo.cpp
index 844fca0..1d7e3da 100644
--- a/foo.cpp
+++ b/foo.cpp
@@ -1,8 +1,15 @@
 #include <QTest>
+#include <QtGlobal> // qgetenv
+#include <QString>
+#include <iostream> // cout
 class Foo : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT
 private slots:
-    void t1() { QVERIFY(true); }
+    void t1() {
+      QString arg = qgetenv("TEST_MSG");
+      std::cout << "Foo arg: " << arg.toStdString() << std::endl;
+      QVERIFY(true);
+    }
 };
 QTEST_MAIN(Foo)
 #include "foo.moc"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your approach.

First of all, `QTEST_MAIN` creates tested object using default ctor. So even if you will create your own `main` function and will use `QTEST_MAIN_IMPL` instead of `QTEST_MAIN` - that will not help you to pass arguments to tested object.

Second issue is that QTest executable will interpret your additional arguments as test filter ([QTest cli reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest-overview.html#qt-test-command-line-arguments)).

But there is another way to configure your test objects. You can use environment variables for that:

```
set(TEST_MSG "hello" CACHE STRING "Message to print from Foo.")
add_test(NAME test COMMAND my_exe "${TEST_MSG}")
set_property(TEST test  PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT_MODIFICATION "CUSTOM_ENV=set:${TEST_MSG}")
```

It will set `CUSTOM_ENV` variable with value `${TEST_MSG}` for you test when it is started from `ctest` command. In tested object you can retrieve that value using `qgetenv("CUSTOM_ENV")`. So it will be possible to define default ctor and use it for any configuration.